# how to filter data in custom list view

Tags: android

herein is my code

```
public class adapters extends Activity implements TextWatcher{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    ListView lv1;
    e E;
    EditText e1;
    LinearLayout ll1;
    LinearLayout ll2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ll1.setBackgroundColor(color.transparent);
        e1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.e1);

    lv1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv1);
        ArrayList<AdapterObject> obj = new ArrayList<AdapterObject>();

        AdapterObject adp; 
        for(int i =0;i<5;i++){

            adp = new AdapterObject();
            adp.setBmp(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.trees));
            adp.setStr("Text "+String.valueOf(i));
            obj.add(adp);
        }

        E = new e(this,2,obj);


        lv1.setAdapter(E);
        lv1.setTextFilterEnabled(true); 

       e1.addTextChangedListener(this);




    }




    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    }


    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
System.out.println(E.getItem(1));
        E.getFilter().filter(e1.getText().toString(), new Filter.FilterListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFilterComplete(int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                System.out.println("tututututu");
                E.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }});
        }
    }






//here is the adapterobject class


public class AdapterObject {

    Drawable bmp;
    String str;
    public Drawable getBmp() {
        return bmp;
    }
    public void setBmp(Drawable bmp) {
        this.bmp = bmp;
    }
    public String getStr() {
        return str;
    }
    public void setStr(String str) {
        this.str = str;
    }


}




//here is class e
public class e extends ArrayAdapter<AdapterObject> {


ArrayList<AdapterObject> Obj;

    Context mContext;
    public e(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            ArrayList<AdapterObject> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        mContext=context;
        Obj=objects;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        LayoutInflater l = (LayoutInflater) (mContext).getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = l.inflate(R.layout.new21, null);
        ImageView btn = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_button);
        TextView text = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.list_text);
        btn.setBackgroundDrawable(Obj.get(position).getBmp());
        text.setText(Obj.get(position).getStr());
        System.out.println("here");
        return v;
            }

    @Override
    public AdapterObject getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.getItem(position);
    }
```

Comment: in the above code i am inflating a row which contains image and a textview

Comment: when i tried the code with a normal listview it works but its not working for a cutom list view

Answer (score 2):

```
edit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
edit.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);

private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher =new TextWatcher()
{
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { 
    mlist.getFilter().filter(edit.getText().toString());

     }  
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after) {  

     }  
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,int count) {  
 }  
};


public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Employee> {
        private ImageButton img;
        private ArrayList<Employee> items;
        private ArrayList<Employee> dupItems;
        public ArrayList<Employee> filtered;
        private Activity currActivity;
        public Employee emp;
        private EmpService empSer;
        private Filter filter;

           public CustomAdapter(Activity context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Employee> empList) {
                super(context, textViewResourceId, empList);
                currActivity = context;
                this.filtered=empList;
                this.items = filtered;
                setNotifyOnChange(true);
                empSer = new EmpService();
               emp=new Employee();

                 }

        public int getCount()
        {
            return items.size();
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View view = convertView;
                if (view == null) {
                    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) currActivity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    view = vi.inflate(R.layout.result, null);
                }
          emp = items.get(position);
          view.setId(emp.empId);
         if (emp  != null) {
        TextView id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        TextView com = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        TextView joindate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        img = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        if (id != null) {
            id.setText(" "+emp.empId);
            }
        if(name != null){
            name.setText(" "+emp.empName);
             }
        if(com != null){
            com.setText(" "+emp.company);
             }
        if(joindate != null){
            joindate.setText(" "+emp.joinDate);

             }

return view;
}
 public void notifyDataSetInvalidated()
 {
  super.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
 }
  @Override
          public Filter getFilter()
          {
              if(filter == null)
                  filter = new MangaNameFilter();
              return filter;
          }
          private class MangaNameFilter extends Filter
          {

              @Override
              protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                  // NOTE: this function is *always* called from a background thread, and
                  // not the UI thread.
                  constraint = edit.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
                  FilterResults result = new FilterResults();
                  if(constraint != null && constraint.toString().length() > 0)
                  {
                      empList=empSer.GetAllDetails();
                      items=empList;
                      ArrayList<Employee> filt = new ArrayList<Employee>();
                      ArrayList<Employee> lItems = new ArrayList<Employee>();
                      synchronized(this)
                      {
                          lItems.addAll(items);
                      }
                      for(int i = 0, l = lItems.size(); i < l; i++)
                      {
                          Employee m = lItems.get(i);
                          if(m.empName.toLowerCase().contains(constraint)||m.joinDate.toLowerCase().contains(constraint)|| m.company.contains(constraint))
                          filt.add(m);
                      }
                      result.count = filt.size();
                      result.values = filt;
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      empList=empSer.GetAllDetails();
                      items=empList;
                      synchronized(this)
                      {
                          result.count = items.size();
                          result.values = items;
                      }
                  }
                  return result;
              }
              @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
              @Override
              protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults result) {
                  // NOTE: this function is *always* called from the UI thread.

                  filtered = (ArrayList<Employee>)result.values;   
                  mlist=new CustomAdapter(currActivity, R.layout.result, filtered);
                  list.setAdapter(mlist);
}
}
```